# Can i divide my class(parent)addition answer in class(child)?

Tags: python, overloading

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def __str__(self):
        return 'addition is(%d)'%(self.x)
    def __add__(self,other):
        c=self.x+other.x
        return a(self.x+other.x)

a1=a(2)`enter code here`
a2=a(5)
c=a1+a2
print(c)

class b(a):
```

can i divide my parent class addition answer(c)=7 in class b and how ?

Comment: What is class b?

Comment: i create a parent class a and do addition in it answer is 7 now i want that answer in child class [class b(a):]  to divide in it

Comment: This seems a bit weird, can you develop on what you need this for? Maybe we can help you better this way.

Comment: solved. thank you for asking :) well my python teacher tell that create class and do addition in it then create a subclass and divide with answer of parent class addition. lsam-sama's  code solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not really sure what you are looking for, but it sounds like you want a child class of a named b, which can do division. Here is what that would look like:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def __str__(self):
        return string(self.x)
    def __add__(self,other):
        c=self.x+other.x
        return a(self.x+other.x)

class b(a):
    def __init__(self,x):
       a.__init__(self, x)

    def __div__(self, other):
       return self.x/other.x

a1 = a(2)
a2 = a(5)
a3 = a1+a2
print(a3)
#7
a4 = b(21)
print(a4/a3)
#3
```

You need a call to initiate the super class to use it in a subclass, which is what

```
def __init__(self,x):
       a.__init__(self, x)
```

does. Once you have that, you can access all the superclass functions and fields, along with functions and fields defined for the subclass.